# Could not find a package configuration file provided by "PkgConf"

Tags: freebsd, jail

I'm trying to build a project using cmake
I use command ccmake and below is the output :

> CMake Version 3.26.1
>
> ```
>  of the following names:
>
>  PkgConfConfig.cmake
>  pkgconf-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of "PkgConf" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
> set    "PkgConf_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
> If    "PkgConf" provides a separate development package or SDK, be
> sure it has    been installed.

I installed pkgconf and I can build all stuff successfully in my original freebsd-14 but when I'm using poudriere bulk command to build the project I come with that error.